# Zend router problem

Tags: zend-framework, router

folks.
I have some problems with zend routes
I have `shops` controller.
It has 3 actions(for now):

- index - lists all of shops using paginator(so I have /shops/?page=2)
- show - shows concrete shop (show/Apple+store)
- search - shows search form

So now I need to make `routing` for that.
I have followin routes

- 'shop', new
  Zend_Controller_Router_Route
  ('/shops/:title',array('controller'
  => 'shops', 'action' => 'show'),array('title' =>
  '/^(?!search$).+$/'))
- 'search_shops',new
  Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static
  ('/shop/search',array('controller' =>
  'shops', 'action' => 'show'))

but when i try to go /shops/Apple+store it says, that there is no Apple store action.
If I ommit regexp part on `shop route`, I can't go to search.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the slashes in the regular expression, i.e.

> new Zend_Controller_Router_Route ('/shops/:title',array('controller' => 'shops', 'action' => 'show'),array('title' => '^(?!search$).+$'))